# Second parameter in knockout applyBindings. Performance implications

Tags: performance, knockout.js

After reading the documentation about the [second parameter in knockout applyBindins](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html), I understand the reason behind it:

> Optionally, you can pass a second parameter to define which part of
>   the document you want to search for data-bind attributes. For example,
>   ko.applyBindings(myViewModel,
>   document.getElementById('someElementId')). This restricts the
>   activation to the element with ID someElementId and its descendants,
>   which is useful if you want to have multiple view models and associate
>   each with a different region of the page.

But I have not seen anything about performance. My thoughts (which are based on nothing) are that it makes sense that ko bindings will work faster if to restring the binding not to the whole document, but to a small part of it.

So does it make sense to use `ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, $('#someElementId')[0])` *without having multiple view models* just for the sake of performance. (I heard about Mr. Knuth, so it would be nice to refrain from optimization citation).

Comment: What do you mean by "bindings will work faster"? *Applying* the bindings is a one-time operation; if it takes any significant amount of time, you're probably dealing with (very) large amounts of static content that would be better generated dynamically using templates.

Comment: @ebohlman I do not mean that binding will work faster. I mean that updating of the elements or adding/removing elements if you bind observable array might be faster. Due to the fact that ko have to find what to update and update that element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

applyBindings is a thin wrapper over applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (which is where ALL the magic happens) and if you don't supply a node it uses window.document.body

There is no difference between calling applyBindings(viewModel) and applyBindings(viewMode,rootNode) unless you have a very large DOM and only want to bind a small fraction.  In this case use the second parameter and Knockout will have a lot less to scan on the initial setup.

Once the bindings are in place they are reacting locally to observable changes, unlike a framework like AngularJS that can potential scan the entire DOM for changes.  The root node is irrelevant at this point.

```
ko.applyBindings = function (viewModel, rootNode) {
    if (rootNode && (rootNode.nodeType !== 1) && (rootNode.nodeType !== 8))
        throw new Error("ko.applyBindings: first parameter should be your view model; second parameter should be a DOM node");
    rootNode = rootNode || window.document.body; // Make "rootNode" parameter optional

    applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal(viewModel, rootNode, true);
};
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed. To know if it scan the DOM on every change to the observable or no. I was not able to properly formulate my question, but in your answer I saw exactly what I wanted.